# What does it mean by "give away control sth to sth" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://youtu.be/0w7mjwp5V40?t=3m15s

> Australia's federal government recently blocked the sale of the nation's largest electrid grid, after a chinese and Hong Kong holdings company attempted to purchase a controlling stake. The government bowed to pressure from opponents of the deal, who said they were **giving away control of their power grid to another country.**

There isn't any word that I don't know in this sentence, but it's hard to understand what it means.

Does "opponents" here mean "a Chinese and Hong Kong holdings company" cause they are the ones who are rejected?

And does "power grid" here mean "the nation's largest electrid grid (company)"? 
Then what does it mean by "give away control of their power grid to another country"?

Comment: to give away control ***of*** something ***to*** someone. power grid means the physical network for distribution of electricity in a place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opponents in this case are the critics of the proposed deal.

A power grid refers to the actual transmission wires, generators, transformers, etc. of a electric company. In this case, yes, it's is the "nation's largest electric grid" mentioned in the first sentence.

And finally, the worry is that a foreign company in control of the electric company would raise rates, defer maintenance and/or other nefarious schemes if they take control of the power company, especially if relations between two countries turn hostile. Hence, the criticism that they would be "giving away control of their power grid to another country".

Comment: But the Australian government is *not* giving away control of their power grid to another country(China and Hong Kong). They *blocked* the sale and didn't allow the chinese companies to buy and control their electric grid... Then the opponents of this deal should suggest that the government has to *allow* the chinese companies to buy the electrid grid..... I'm still so confused now, what have I missed here??

Comment: @dbwlsld Right, it was blocked. And the  opponents were SAYING before it was blocked that it would be giving it away if it had happened. The opponents are not suggesting anything. ***The author of the article is describing why the opponents were opposed to it at that time***.